# How to share multiple Voice Memos instead of one by one? (post iOS 12)

Tags: ios, voice-memo

If I remember correctly, one could share multiple recordings at the same time with a share extension using the old version. This doesn't seem to be true with the post iOS 12 version.

Comment: Transfer all raw files to a mac/PC, share as you like. No way to do it in iOS.